# When to check the content of transaction proposal in corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

In corda document says that even if transactions are contractually valid, contents of transactions should be checked before signing. However, flow seem to automate transaction signing process.
How and when to check transaction's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they meant is, when you receive a request to sign a transaction (i.e. you are the node that's running the responder flow); you shouldn't just blindly sign. I understand that the process is "automatic", but your automatic signature should be preceded with some business rules validation.

For instance in the `cordapp-example` of the samples repo; the responder doesn't immediately sign; instead, first it checks that the received transaction produces an output of the expected type (i.e. IOU); otherwise someone for instance can send you a transaction with a different state of type Cash where you are the previous owner and they are the new owner, so if you sign without checking the state type; it's as if you gave them money!

Then the responder checks that the IOU amount doesn't exceed a certain limit; so even though the initiator fulfilled all the required validations to get an IOU from you, that doesn't mean you're going to approve any amount; meaning let's say you're a Bank and someone gave you all the documentation to get a loan approval, that doesn't mean you're going to give them any amount they request (e.g. 10 Million $).

See the code here: 
https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/018502310b56bc1bb31440380af4b89e9bbd7ed8/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt#L105

Comment: Grate explanation. Code helped understanding.  Besides contractual correctness flow also contains validation steps.

Answer (score 1):

[Dan Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8025412/dan-newton) wrote an excellent post on how to approach flow responders which shows what kind of checks can be made: https://lankydan.dev/responder-flow-validation